# Android - Using SVGMapView

Tags: android, svg

I'm developing an android app where I want to display a SVG indoor map. I've found the following library: https://github.com/jiahuanyu/SVGMapView that can be used to achieve this. Even though the library is not supported any longer, I cannot see any dependencies to add the gradle file in order to utilize the contents of the library. Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not good practice to use **[No Longer Support]** library but for using that you must 
first download it from github

1) copy library folder to your project path (in base folder-use file maneger Don't copy in android studio)

2) add this line to your build.gradle app level

```
dependencies {
    //others dependencies 
    implementation project(path: ':library')
}
```

3) change `settings.gradle` to this

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

4)Sync project